# How to Properly Define UTF-8 Charset in in <head> Tag Section of Web Document

Tags: utf-8, doctype, head

If my doc type is `<!DOCTYPE html>` is it best or more correct to use

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

to define utf-8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is only valid with HTML5.
The second one is also valid for older (X)HTML versions

With this doctype (indicating HTML5) both are valid, I prefer the first as it is shorter. :)